# How to plot multiple CSV files with separate plots for each category

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 3 CSV files. All file contains one column (`column name: Method`). There are 4 different types of methods contains in each CSV file.

I can create a `plot` that contains all 4 methods for 1 CSV file. The code is given below

```
ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
CSVS = [
    ROOT / "CSV_1.csv",
    ROOT / "CSV_2.csv",
    ROOT / "CSV_3.csv",
]

def accuracy_plot():
    for csv in CSVS:
        error_kind = csv.stem[: csv.stem.find("_")]
        data = pd.read_csv(csv)
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
        sns.scatterplot(x="EC", y="MAE", data=data, hue="Method")
        plt.title("MAE vs EC")
        plt.xlabel("MAE")
        plt.ylabel("EC")
        plt.savefig(error_kind + ".png")
```

The plot looks like the below one [image: PLot]

Now, I want to create a plot for one method and data that comes from all CSV files. More specifically, I want a plot that shows only one method's info but data from all 3 CSV files. In this plot, I need to use different signs (+, -, *) to identify the data that comes from different datasets. Or we can also give them a different color. Ultimately, I will have 4 different plots for 4 different methods.

Could you tell me how can I do this job? I used `seaborn` but you are most welcome if you want to use `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

1. The simplest way I can think is to combine all the files into a single dataframe
2. Plot the dataframe with [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html)

- This option creates a single FacetGrid

```py
# create the dataframe from all the csv files
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv).assign(file=csv.stem) for csv in CSVS]).reset_index(drop=True)

# create the plots
p = sns.relplot(data=df, kind='scatter', col='Method', col_wrap=2, x='EC', y='MAE', hue='file', height=4)

# save
p.savefig("output.png")
```

[image]

### Option 2

- As requested in the edit, this option will create separate plots for each `method`.

1. Add a column to the dataframe to identify which file the data is from, using [`.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html). Using `.assign`, instead of a for-loop, came from [Simon Bowly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9017455/simon-bowly).
2. Select `data` for the given `method`, and use `hue='file'`
3. Set `hue_order`, to ensure the same color is assigned within each plot.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matpltlib.pyplot as plt

# create a single dataframe
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv).assign(file=csv.stem) for csv in CSVS]).reset_index(drop=True)

# plot
for method in df.Method.unique():
    # select data only for the current method
    data = df[df.Method.eq(method)]
    sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='EC', y='MAE', hue='file', hue_order=sorted(df.file.unique()))
    plt.title(method)
    plt.xlim(0, 1)
    plt.savefig(f'{method}.png')
    plt.show() or plt.clf()  # to clear the plot between each loop; pick one
```

[image]

### Sample Data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def data(method, loc):
    n = 100
    v = np.random.normal(loc=loc, scale=0.01, size=(n,))
    m = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=120.0, size=(n,))
    f = np.random.choice(['csv_1', 'csv_2', 'csv_3'], size=(n,))
    met = [method] * n
    d = {'EC': v, 'MAE': m, 'Method': met, 'file': f}
    return pd.DataFrame(d)


samples = [('method_1', 0.05), ('method_1', 0.12),
           ('method_2', 0.053), ('method_2', 0.11), ('method_2', 0.21),
           ('method_3', 0.63), ('method_3', 0.72), ('method_3', 0.9),
           ('method_4', 0.7), ('method_4', 0.8), ('method_4', 0.9)]

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.concat([data(method, loc) for (method, loc) in samples]).reset_index(drop=True)
```